# GCC generates useless instructions?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

```
BOOL32 doStuff() {
    return TRUE;
}
```

gcc 2.95 for vxworks 5.x, compiling the above code with `-O0` for 32-bit x86 generated following code:

```
          doStuff:
0e9de190:   push    %ebp
0e9de191:   mov     %esp,%ebp
 308          return TRUE;
0e9de193:   mov     $0x1,%eax
0e9de198:   jmp     0xe9de1a0 <doStuff+16>
 312      {
0e9de19a:   lea     0x0(%esi),%esi
// The JMP jumps here
0e9de1a0:   mov     %ebp,%esp
0e9de1a2:   pop     %ebp
0e9de1a3:   ret
```

Everything looks normal until the JMP and LEA instruction.  What are they for?

---

My guess is that it is some kind of alignment, but I am not sure about this.

I would have done something like this:

```
          doStuff:
0e9de190:   push    %ebp
0e9de191:   mov     %esp,%ebp
 308          return TRUE;
0e9de193:   mov     $0x1,%eax
0e9de1XX:   mov     %ebp,%esp
0e9de1XX:   pop     %ebp
0e9de1XX:   ret
0e9de1XX:   fill with lea 0x0, %esi
```

Comment: What code did you write that was eventually translated into the assembly generated above? You should include this information to increase the chances of getting help.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? What platform/OS?

Comment: Added infos hope this helps

Comment: Looking at code compiled at `-O0` is a complete and utter waste of time. The compiler not only doesn't *care* about generating optimal code, it will sometimes generate pathologically *sub-optimal* code in order to make debugging easier (e.g., allow you to set breakpoints). The only disassembly you should look at is for optimized code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lea     0x0(%esi),%esi` is a long NOP, and the jmp is jumping over it.  You probably have an **ancient** version of binutils (containing `as`) to go with your ancient gcc version.

So when gcc put a `.p2align` to align a label in the middle of the function that isn't otherwise a branch target (for some bizarre reason, but it's -O0 so it's not even supposed to be good code), the assembler made a long NOP and jumped over it.

Normally you'd only jump over a block of NOPs if there were a lot of them, especially if they were all single-byte NOPs.  This is really dumb code, so stop using such crusty tools.  You could try upgrading your assembler (but still using gcc2.95 if you need to).  Or check that it doesn't happen at `-O2` or `-O3`, in which case it doesn't matter.

If you have to keep using gcc2.95 for some reason, then just be aware that it's ancient, and this is part of the tradeoff you're making to keep using whatever it is that's forcing you to use it.

Comment: With -O2 it looks much better ^^